# Problem with Java GUI implementation

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a problem with the code I am currently trying to run - I am trying to make 3 buttons, put them on a GUI, and then have the first buttons colour be changed to orange, and the buttons next to that colour change to white and green. Every click thereafter will result in the colours moving one button to the right. My code thus far is as follows, it is skipping colours in places and is not behaving at all as I expected. Can anyone offer some help/guidance please ?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ButtonJava extends JButton implements ActionListener  {
  private int currentColor=-1;
  private int clicks=0;
  private static final Color[] COLORS = {
    Color.ORANGE,
    Color.WHITE,
    Color.GREEN };
  private static ButtonJava[] buttons;

  public ButtonJava( ){
    setBackground( Color.YELLOW );
    setText( "Pick ME" );
    this.addActionListener( this );
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("JFrame");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel( );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    buttons = new ButtonJava[3];
    for(int i = 0;i<buttons.length ; i++){
      buttons[i] = new ButtonJava(); 
      panel.add(buttons[i]);
    }
    frame.getContentPane( ).add( panel );
    frame.setSize( 500, 500);
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }

  private void updateButton() {
     clicks++;
    changeColors();
//    setText( );
  }

private void changeColors( ) {
  for (int i=buttons.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    buttons[i].currentColor = nextColor(currentColor);
    buttons[i].setBackground(COLORS[buttons[i].currentColor]);
    buttons[i].setText(("# of clicks = " + buttons[i].getClicks() ) );
  }
}

private Integer getClicks() {
 return clicks;
}

private int nextColor( int curCol ) {
  final int colLen = COLORS.length;
  curCol--;
  curCol = (colLen + curCol % colLen) % colLen;
  return curCol;
}

private void firstClick( ActionEvent event ) {
  int curCol = 0;
  for (int i=buttons.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if ( buttons[i] == event.getSource() ) {
      buttons[i].currentColor = curCol;
      curCol++;
      currentColor++;
    }
  }}

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) {
    if ( -1 == currentColor ) {
      firstClick( event );
    }
    updateButton( );   
  }


}
```

Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: The OP already has 4 suggestions from posting this question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938149/java-gui-is-being-created-but-event-is-not-triggering-anything

Comment: @camickr: same code, different problem. Agreed though that its better off as an edit to yesterday's question.

Comment: @camickr I fixed the suggestions that were made there, it still doesn't work, hence I am looking for more help...

Comment: @user476033: it's often better to update the original question with the details of your new problem. That way, the people who are already familiar with your code will have easier access, and there's less volume of questions for people to sort through.

Comment: @Mac: Thanks for the constructive feedback, I will bear that in mind from now on ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple issues with the code you posted, but they generally boil down to being clear about what is a member of the class(static) and what is a member of the instance.

For starters, you `buttons` array only exists inside your main method and can't be accessed by `changeColors()`. Along those same lines, since `changeColors()` is an instance method, `setBackground()` needs to be called directly on the button in your array. as written you are setting the color for one button 3 times.

Additionally, the logic in `changeColors()` is not properly rotating the `currentColor` index. You need to both increase the counter and ensure is wraps for the length of the color array. If the arrays are the same size, you need to make sure there is an extra addition to make the colors cycle.

```
private static void changeColors( ) {
  for (int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].setBackground(COLORS[currentColor]);
    currentColor = nextColor(currentColor);
  }
  if (buttons.length == COLORS.length) {
    currentColor = nextColor(currentColor);
  }
}

private static int nextColor(int currentColor) {
  return (currentColor+1)% COLORS.length;
}
```

**Edit for new code:**

I'm not sure why you re-wrote `nextColor()`, as what I posted worked. But in general, I feel like you are running into issues because your code is not well partitioned for the tasks you are trying to achieve. You have code related to the specific button instance and code related to controlling all the buttons mixing together.

With the following implementation, the issue of how many times a button was clicked is clearly self-contained in the button class. Then every button press also calls the one method in the owning panel. This method knows how many buttons there are and the color of the first button. And each subsequent button will contain the next color in the list, wrapping when necessary.

```
public class RotateButtons extends JPanel {
  private static final Color[] COLORS = { Color.ORANGE, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN };
  private static final int BUTTON_COUNT = 3;
  private JButton[] _buttons;
  private int _currentColor = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new RotateButtons());
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public RotateButtons()
  {
    _buttons = new JButton[BUTTON_COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < _buttons.length; i++) {
      _buttons[i] = new CountButton();
      add(_buttons[i]);
    }
  }

  private void rotateButtons()
  {
    for (JButton button : _buttons) {
      button.setBackground(COLORS[_currentColor]);
      _currentColor = nextColor(_currentColor);
    }
    if (_buttons.length == COLORS.length) {
      _currentColor = nextColor(_currentColor);
    }
  }

  private int nextColor(int currentColor)
  {
    return (currentColor + 1) % COLORS.length;
  }

  private class CountButton extends JButton {
    private int _count = 0;

    public CountButton()
    {
      setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
      setText("Pick ME");
      addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
          _count++;
          setText("# of clicks = " + _count);
          rotateButtons();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**2nd Edit:**

Shows just the changes to shift `_currentColor` by the necessary amount on the first click.

```
public class RotateButtons extends JPanel {
  ...
  private boolean _firstClick = true;
  ...
  private void rotateButtons(CountButton source)
  {
    if (_firstClick) {
      _firstClick = false;
      boolean foundSource = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < _buttons.length; i++) {
        if (foundSource) {
          _currentColor = nextColor(_currentColor);
        } else {
          foundSource = _buttons[i] == source;
        }
      }
    }
    ...
  }

  private class CountButton extends JButton {
    ...

    public CountButton()
    {
      ...
      addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
          ...
          rotateButtons(CountButton.this);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: +1: I should have realised that `buttons` was local to `main`. Well spotted.

Comment: Thanks for this response ! One thing I am having trouble with though, I need to make the buttons array visible in the changeColours() method...what is the cleanest way to go about doing this ? Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: When I was testing the code, I made the array a static member of the class. However, in a real implementation, it would makes sense to have the class that owns the panel also own the array. In fact I would not extend JButton and put all the code in a subclass of `JPanel`. This way you have one panel that knows how buttons on it work, rather than a button class that assumes certain things about itself and forces the class that uses it to use it correctly.

Comment: Thank you unholysampler ! I have been playing around a bit now and changed a lot of things, I think I have the right form, it's just the updateButton() and nextColor methods aren't working as I'd hoped !

Comment: @user476033: I updated my answer with a full implementation. If it still isn't what you are looking for, try to specifically say what it is doing and why that is wrong for your end goal.

Comment: @unholysampler , that is brilliant and so helpful, thank you very much. The only problem with your code is that I would like to to make the first button clicked always initialise to the colour orange, I cannot figure out how to do this for the life of me. This is the reason for my firstClick() method above, though it is not fulfiling its purpose as it stands! Thank you again for all your help and sorry for being a nuisance :).

Comment: @user476033: New edit to show how to pass in the button that triggered the event and adjust the current color on the first click.

Comment: @unholysampler: Thank you so much for all the help, you are amazing ! :) I'm sorry though, I should have mentioned that I would like to do this all in one class, is it possible to do what you have done above using only a single class ? Thank you very much and sorry I didn't say that earlier !:(

Comment: @user476033: You _can_, but I think trying to do that was the cause of most of the issues you were having. As written, the second class is private nested class means that everything is contained within the single class and not accessible elsewhere in your code base.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I noticed is you are using `currentColor` to assign the color, but the `currentColor` is initialized to ***0*** and the only manipulation is `currentColor %= 2` which does not change it.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you are wanting to achieve, I'm thinking to change `currentColor %= 2` to `++currentColor`, and `setBackground(COLORS[currentColor]);` to `buttons[i].setBackground(COLORS[(i + currentColor) % 3]);`. That way, your colours should cycle around your buttons each time one is clicked.

**EDIT:** it's probably also worth calling `changeColors` from within `main` to initialise your button colours. And, as @unholysampler notes, your array `buttons` is local to `main` and should (for example) be refactored as a static member variable, and have `changeColors` become a static method.